# svg css animation changes position and size, and I just want it to change size

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make a  element in an svg to get bigger and smaller for an animation I'm working on.

I've added a simplified svg to demonstrate what I am running into.

what is happening is the box is getting bigger (good), but its also moving down from the top (bad), I want it to stay in place.

I want the center of the square to stay in place while it grows bigger in the Y direction.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>


<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 640 640" width="640" height="640">
<style>

    path{
        animation: shine-1 1s infinite linear; 
    }


    @keyframes shine-1 {
        from{
            transform: scaleY(0);
        }
        to{
            transform: scaleY(1);
        }
    }
</style>
<defs><path d="M237.65 286.88L379.91 286.88L379.91 394.87L237.65 394.87L237.65 286.88Z" id="j122ygNii7"></path></defs><g><g><g><use xlink:href="#j122ygNii7" opacity="1" fill="#dc9bd9" fill-opacity="1"></use></g></g></g></svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

what I needed was a transform-origin attribute and the transform-box attribute after the animation.
it needs to have its transform origin at the center with 50% 50%
it also critically needs the transform-box set to fill-box.

then all animations are relative to the position they are in.

```
.class{
        animation: spin-grow-ect 3s infinite linear;
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform-box: fill-box;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can made a div and insert the svg inside, so it will get bigger without going down.Like this

```html
<div id="square">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 640 640" width="640" height="640">

<defs><path d="M237.65 286.88L379.91 286.88L379.91 394.87L237.65 394.87L237.65 286.88Z" id="j122ygNii7"></path></defs><g><g><g><use xlink:href="#j122ygNii7" opacity="1" fill="#dc9bd9" fill-opacity="1"></use></g></g></g></svg>
</div>

<style>

    #square{
        animation: shine-1 1s infinite linear; 
    }


    @keyframes shine-1 {
        from{
            transform: scaleY(0);
        }
        to{
            transform: scaleY(1);
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: that's not going to work for me, unfortunately, I'm working with several elements inside this svg, I'm trying to make a group of them grow and shrink.